# How can I apply the style(sheet) of one QtWidget (e. g. QTreeWidget) to another widget (e. g. QLabel)?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlabel

I ran the below MCVE snippet on two different systems which produced the windows depicted in the screenshots. As you can see, their border styles differ. I do not mind that. The border styles are allowed to differ on the two systems. However, for one system, I'd like the border style of both QtWidgets to be the same. The border style of `QLabel` doesn't seem to be set, yet.

How can I set the border style of the `QLabel` to the same border style as the `QTreeWidget`?

---

**MCVE snippet**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        treewidget = QTreeWidget(self)
        label = QLabel(self)
        label.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; min-height: 200px;")
        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.setSpacing(10)
        grid.addWidget(treewidget, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(label, 2, 0)
        self.setLayout(grid)
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    f = widget()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**Screenshot from two different systems**

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your general question is impossible to solve for the following reasons:

- The properties of a widget are not shared by other widgets.
- The values of certain properties have default values and are highly dependent on the decision of the Qt developers, such as the edge of QLabel, that is, the edge can be modified but the default value can not be read.
- Not all visual elements can be modified with Qt Style Sheet, in reality it is very limited, it is often better to create a customized QStyle.

But your particular problem can be solved, in this case we set the border to none.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

QSS = '''
QTreeWidget{ 
    border: None 
}
QLabel{
    background-color: white; 
    min-height: 200px;
}
'''

class widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        treewidget = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget()
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel()

        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        grid.setSpacing(10)
        grid.addWidget(treewidget, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(label, 2, 0)
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(QSS)
    f = widget()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]